# Prove that mean independent random variables are uncorrelated

Tags: probability-theory

I need to prove $E(X|Y) = E(X)$ implies $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$

Is my proof correct?

$ E(X)E(Y) = E(X) \int yf_Y(y)dy $

$= \int E(X)  yf_Y(y)dy$   ....   ($E(X)$ is a constant)

$ = \int(\int  xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx)  yf_Y(y)dy$ ...... (given $E(X|Y) = E(X)$)

$ = \int\int  xyf_{X|Y}(x|y)  f_Y(y)dxdy$

$ = \int\int  xyf_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy$
$=E(XY)$

I'm confused because it was suggested that the law of iterated expectations was to be applied, and I haven't done that. Can anyone suggest a proof using the law of iterated expectations?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my proof correct?

It is, provided that densities and conditional densities exist, which is not always the case.

> Can anyone suggest a proof using the law of iterated expectations?

Here it is: $E(XY)=E(E(XY\mid Y))=E(E(X\mid Y)Y)=E(E(X)Y)=E(X)E(Y)$. (To the OP: you should be able to justify every equal sign in this, if you are not, just whistle.)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to follow the steps. I seem to have taken a much more long winded and less complete approach.

Answer (score 2):

$\checkmark$ You proof works. (Provided the pdf of $X,Y$ and $X\cap Y$ exist.)

Using the Law of Iterated Expectation is quite similar.

$\begin{align}
 \mathsf E_X(X)\;\mathsf E_Y(Y) & = \mathsf E_Y(Y\;\mathsf E_{X}(X)) & \text{since the expectation of $X$ is a constant}
\\ & = \mathsf E_Y(Y\;\mathsf E_{X\mid Y}(X\mid Y)) & \text{by the equality }\mathsf E_X[X]=\mathsf E_{X\mid Y}(X\mid Y)
\\ & = \mathsf E_Y(\mathsf E_{X\mid Y}(XY\mid Y)) & \text{since $Y$ is constant for any given $Y$}
\\ & = \mathsf E_{X,Y}(XY) & \text{by the L.I.E.}
\end{align}$

Comment: There is no use in adding subscripts to every expectation operator E one meets. You might try to get rid of these, and you will see that the air feels lighter...

Comment: @Did While the subscripts are often omitted it's sometimes less ambiguous to include them. It *is* possibly a little redundant in this case though.

Comment: What would be a situation where it is less ambiguous to include the subscripts? I know none.

Comment: Unrelated: what is $X\cap Y$?