# A question on conditional expectation leading to zero covariance and vice versa

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, covariance

In my probability class I was tackled with this seemingly weird question involving conditional expectation:

> Let X,Y be two random variables (it is not mentioned whether or not they are discrete or continuous) and we are asked the following:
>
> 1. For all constants $ \beta $ we have $ E[X | Y = \beta] = E[X] $
> 2. $ cov(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] = 0 $
>
> The problem: we are asked to prove or give a counterexample to 1 leads to 2 and to 2 leads to 1

I have tried to prove these two directions but got nothing just by looking at the definitions and so I thought maybe they are false and we are to give counterexamples but I got nothing there either. Looking at the covariance formula I see Y is involved but I cannot really seem to incorporate it from conditional expectation given, so I am stuck and need help. Thanks to all.

Comment: If 1. holds then $E(XY)=E(E(X\mid Y)Y)=$ $____$ hence $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)=$ $__$. In the other direction, choose $X=Y^2$ and assume that the distributions of $Y$ and $-Y$ coincide then $E(XY)=E(Y)=0$ hence $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)=0$ but $E(X\mid Y)=$ $__$ $\ne E(X)$.

Comment: @Did: Thanks I get the one direction but regarding the counterexample, how do you mean choose Y such that -Y and Y have the same distribution?

Comment: The first condition is called "mean independence." See, e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967641/prove-that-mean-independent-random-variables-are-uncorrelated

Comment: @zbigniew2015 Well, what I mean is "choose Y such that -Y and Y have the same distribution". No example which springs to mind?

Comment: @Did : would a standard normal distribution work?

Comment: Are you asking me whether Y and -Y are identically distributed when Y is standard normal?

Comment: @Did : I think the answer is yes to that question